# After changing JLabel text it will not reposition

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, jdialog

I have a JDialog with a title written at the top. I call this JDialog for two different cases and if it is not the default I change the text to something else. This works fine but the position is then too far to the right.

I have tried numerous methods such as:

```
    TitleText.setText("Edit Fuse");
    TitleText.setAlignmentY(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    //TitleText.setHorizontalAlignment(JDialog.);
    //TitleText.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

None of them even move the text. I am using a Free Design Layout for the entire JDialog. If I must I'll just create another JLable and hide/unhide but I thought this would be simple. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using a Free Design Layout for the entire JDialog

- Don't do this if you want the title JLabel's text to be at the top and be centered. Instead have the JDialog's main JPanel use BorderLayout, and add the JLabel to it BorderLayout.PAGE_START, also known as BorderLayout.North.
- The main JPanel can then hold the rest of your GUI, likely in its own JPanel, using its own layout manager, and other JPanels, in its BorderLayout.CENTER position.
- Also, don't use `JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT`, a float, but rather use `JLabel.CENTER`, an int, which is the appropriate parameter for the setHorizontalAlignment(...) method.
- Finally, I must give you an unsolicitated side recommendation to be sure that your variable names begin with a lower-case letters and not upper case letters so that they comply with Java naming rules. This is important if you want others, such as folks here who'd like to help you, to rapidly understand your code.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LayoutExample extends JPanel {
   private static final float SIZE = 32;
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 2000;
   private String[] TITLE_STRINGS = { "Title 1", "Title 2",
         "Some Random Title", "Fubars Rule!", "Snafus Drool!" };
   private int titleIndex = 0;
   private JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(TITLE_STRINGS[titleIndex],
         JLabel.CENTER);

   public LayoutExample() {
      titleLabel.setFont(titleLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, SIZE));

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

      // the rest of your GUI could be added below
      add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(500, 300)), BorderLayout.CENTER);

      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            titleIndex++;
            titleIndex %= TITLE_STRINGS.length;
            titleLabel.setText(TITLE_STRINGS[titleIndex]);
         }
      }).start();
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("LayoutExample");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new LayoutExample());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I'm new to layouts, didn't know I could just put it on a JPanel.